# Using Eclipse for Android App: App won't install freshly because it's already on the device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way to always do a fresh install when I'm "Running" my Android app for testing on either a real device or an emulator. It always tells me "No need to install because application is already on device", then just launches the main Intent.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you always need a fresh install? Eclipse should autoamtically make a new install if code was changed.

Comment: The only change is an image in the RES folder, therefore Eclipse isn't detecting any changes. I guess I'll just have to rename the image in an XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need make a code change and recompile for Eclipse to push out a fresh copy of the app to your phone, otherwise it skips the reinstall step since its unnecessary.

You could manually uninstall the app from your phone if you want to force a fresh install.

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily have to make changes to the code. You can clean the project via Eclipse (via Project->Clean menu in Eclipse IDE and then selecting the project you want). That will recompile your code and reinstall the app.